# Hyper-V Machine harddisk full, but not so

Tags: windows-server-2008, hard-drive, hyper-v

My virtual machine is having harddisk issues, at least that is what Hyper-V says.
The VM has 20 gb available and is running ubuntu 14.x server.
Its current usage is 4.7 GB and hyper-v pauses it time to time stating it has no free space on its harddisk. I can resume it without any errors... what can be the issue, that hyper-v comes to that conclusion that is has no space?

Comment: hyper-v tell you there is no free space in the host on the volume on which the virtual machine resides, not in the virtual machine

Comment: Just checked; the physical free space on that partition is over 870 GB, so that cannot be the problem. Also there is another VM running that uses over 50GB and has no issues.